# Vuetify: how to appear v-text-field label inside input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to that label appear inside the input field. See below:

[image: Here is what I want to look like]

In the vuetify version 2.4.9, I choose the filled property and add CSS to build up the border with the codepen below:

https://codepen.io/magooo/pen/JjELwrx

```
.theme--light.v-text-field--filled > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}
```

But I find out the border-bottom of v-text-field is overlapping.And I can't change the border color to primary when I tap the v-text-field.

Can someone help me to fix the problem? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom border of the input is placed via `:before` of the `.v-input__slot`,
https://codepen.io/eligiv/pen/wvgmbjX

I put the `:before` in `display: none` & design the main input (via `scss`).

Hope its helped!

Comment: Thanks for your help!But I have still one problem can't fix it.Is there a way to add border color on border-top,border-right,border-left when I click on the v-text-field?To make the border appear just like the border-bottom.Thanks in advance :)